# Public Upload into a Picasa Album

Tags: picasa-web-albums

Is there any way to Create a Public Upload Page to a picasa Album  so that whom ever I give the link to can upload images to my picasa Album ?

Answer (score 2):

You can enable the upload by email feature of Picasa.

This will allow you to setup an email address to which you send an email with pictures that will be posted directly in a Picasa Album. More info [here.](http://picasa.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=83342)

Comment: Thanks but that is not an option.